# Deploying Angular app in helion stackato

Tags: angular, stackato

how to deploy a angular 4 app in helion stackato?
http://docs.stackato.com/admin/console/sample-applications.html

I tried the create menifest.yml file and push in stackto but it is not working.

I am not able to get any sample yml file for angular4 js.

Answer (score 0):

So you have a static HTML/JS app build with Angular4 and you'd like to deploy it? From what I recall my Stackato time, static buildpack was used to deploy such apps (https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/buildpacks/staticfile/index.html).

What are the errors you are getting?